# Updating kernel version from 3.2 to 3.8.0 wired connection not working in 12.04(LTS)

Tags: 12.04, networking, kernel, network-manager, wired

After updating kernel version from 3.2 to 3.8.0 wired connection not working in 12.04(LTS)

```
$ uname -r
3.8.0-030800-generic


$ ifconfig -a
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:2a:70:cd:f2:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e2a:70ff:fecd:f2c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:24547
          TX packets:3081 errors:11 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2677978 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:517085 (517.0 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:51116 (51.1 KB)  TX bytes:51116 (51.1 KB)



$ lshw -C network: 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:2a:70:cd:f2:c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.



$ sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:
 change the line managed=false to managed=true
Save, stop and start network manager:


sudo service network-manager restart
```

But Wired connection not showing.

How to connect wired network ?

How to resolve this ?

Comment: friends, i resolved this issue on that day itself

Comment: > friends, i resolved this issue on that day itself – Ubuntu-Beginner
> Feb 23 at 13:15 How can you resolve it?. I just got the same problem

Comment: download and install the lan driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download and install the required driver. after that wired network works fine

http://r8168dl.appspot.com/files/r8168-8.039.00.tar.bz2